# How to configure gwt application on tomcat for debugging?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, tomcat

I am trying to debug a GWT application on Tomcat, but I don't know how to run/debug my application on Tomcat in Eclipse. I have so many links but I can't get a proper result.

I'm using `-noserver -port 8080` and war file configuration but every time I get an error 404 while I run the application.

Here are some links that I follow but I can't configure:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/7511aca28b5f683c

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_in_eclipse_for_java_ee

http://jxpang.blogspot.in/2010/11/configure-external-tomcat-7-server-in.html

update

I am having same url but i think i am doing wrong configuration. is any body has proper solution for configure gwt web application with apche tomcat  with debugging.

I want step by step configuration and running tutorial 
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you connect to the local server, but it can't resolve your URL?
If you stick with all the defaults, then in dev-mode you would use the following URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

But when configured on an external server you would need:

http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Also make sure that in the 'Server' tab of your Debug configuration the option Run built in server is unchecked.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse: right-click on your GWT project, and choose "Run As web Application (running on an external server)"

Then you can fill the field External root server (dns/ip and webapps folder for tomcat)